# using list equate to a variable in if statement in python.the statement is always output the first condition

Tags: python

**the output is always printing out the first condition whatever the input**

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    pos=input("input the position frm 1-9")
    if pos!=list:
     **#output is always this**
     print('err001//oops....invalid entry try again XD')
     game_boardf()
    elif pos!='_':
     print("err002//alredy occupied try again")
     game_boardf()
    else:
     pos=int(pos)-1
     game_board[pos]=current_player
     game_boardf()
    **#whole project
    [1]: https://repl.it/@dokisuru/ttme**
```

Comment: `pos` is a string, `list` is a list. Why would the be equal? I think you want `if int(pos) in list:`

Comment: `input` gives you a string. if you wish to check whether the number is in a list. you need to convert the string to an int and then check if the int is in the list. other than this, you have a few minor problems

Comment: i see now,hate being a nooob,thaks guys